# How can I convert the tiger hash values from the official implementations into the form used by Direct Connect?

Tags: hash, cryptography

I am trying to implement a [Direct Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Connect_%28file_sharing%29) Client, and I am currently stuck at a point where I need to hash the files in order to be able to upload them to other clients.

As the all other clients require a TTHL ([Tiger Tree Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_tree#Tiger_tree_hash) Leaves) support for verification of the downloaded data. I have searched for implementations of the algorithm, and found [tiger-hash-python](https://github.com/browning/tiger-hash-python/).

I have implemented a routine that uses the hash function from before, and is able to hash large files, according to the logic specified in [Tree Hash EXchange format (THEX)](http://zgp.org/pipermail/p2p-hackers/2002-June/000622.html) (basically, the tree diagram is the important part on that page).

However, the value produced by it is similar to those [shown on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_%28cryptography%29#Examples), a hex digest, but is different from those shown in the DC clients I'm using for reference.

I have been unable to find out how the hex digest form is converted to this other one (39 characters, A-Z, 0-9). Could someone please explain how that is done?

---

Well ... I tried what Paulo Ebermann said, using the following functions:

```
def strdivide(list,length):
    result = []
    # Calculate how many blocks there are, using the condition: i*length = len(list).
    # The additional maths operations are to deal with the last block which might have a smaller size
    for i in range(0,int(math.ceil(float(len(list))/length))):
        result.append(list[i*length:(i+1)*length])
    return result
def dchash(data):
    result = tiger.hash(data) # From the aformentioned tiger-hash-python script, 48-char hex digest
    result = "".join([ "".join(strdivide(result[i:i+16],2)[::-1]) for i in range(0,48,16) ]) # Representation Transform
    bits = "".join([chr(int(c,16)) for c in strdivide(result,2)]) # Converting every 2 hex characters into 1 normal
    result = base64.b32encode(bits) # Result will be 40 characters
    return result[:-1] # Leaving behind the trailing '='
```

The TTH for an empty file was found to be `8B630E030AD09E5D0E90FB246A3A75DBB6256C3EE7B8635A`, which after the transformation specified [here](https://github.com/gtk-gnutella/bitter/blob/master/checks.sh), becomes `5D9ED00A030E638BDB753A6A24FB900E5A63B8E73E6C25B6`. Base-32 encoding this result yielded `LWPNACQDBZRYXW3VHJVCJ64QBZNGHOHHHZWCLNQ`, which was found to be what DC++ generates.

Comment: I think a TTH is usually base32 and not base16/hex encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only mention of the format of the hash in the Direct Connect protocol I found is on the [$SR page on the NMDC Protocol wiki](http://wiki.gusari.org/index.php?title=$SR):

> For files containing TTH, the <hub_name> parameter is replaced with `TTH:<base32_encoded_tth_hash>` (ref: TTH_Hash).

So, it is Base32-encoding. This is defined in RFC 4648 (and some earlier ones), [section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-6).
Basically, you are using the capital letters A-Z and the decimal digits 2 to 7, and one base32 digit represents 5 bits, while one base16 (hexadecimal) digit represents only 4 ones.

This means, each 5 hex digits map to 4 base32-digits, and for a Tiger hash (192 bits) you will need 40 base32-digits (in the official encoding, the last one would be a `=` padding, which seems to be omitted if you say that there are always 39 characters).

I'm not sure of an implementation of a conversion from hex (or bytes) to base32, but it shouldn't be too complicated with a lookup table and some bit-shifting.